# What service is behind the referrer "android.clients.google.com"?

Tags: android, amazon-cloudfront, referrer

From Cloudfront report I can see a few thousands download requests on one file attributed to the referrer "android.clients.google.com", any idea about what is behind this referrer?

Comment: We can see the same for our application. This referer does only appear with the download requests. And always with the same user agent (that does not fit the user agent the user has in this session). We assume it has to be some malware on android. But this is just a guess right now.

Comment: @schouk That could be it because I found this referrer associated with only a unique IP from Japan with Windows XP as User-Agent. This IP tried to download our file 17k times in a few minutes.

Comment: same here. Always the same User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.8) Firefox/3.6.8". But unfortunately different IPs. We also see many many downloads per minute...

Comment: @Joël We are experiencing the same problem from some days ago. The same user agent and android.clients.google.com. Any news on this? We are investigating it too.

Comment: @MarcCals No news.. It only happened once here. It looks suspicious for sure

Comment: We're seeing the same pattern here. Same referrer, same user agent. I thought it might be some badly written malware which tries to hijack file downloads from other apps.

Comment: When I block this domain, I can no longer use google play.